# Is this the correct approach to build 'super structure' classes in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to build a class that I can use to instantiate new work projects from. The idea is that each project will call upon resources from different departments and I need to be able to implement if needed- within the <kbd>Project</kbd> object. Each <kbd>Department</kbd> should be able to access project-level attributes and methods, as well as the project object being able to access individual departments attributes (i.e. for summing departmental costs to return overall project cost).

Below is some pseudo code of what I am trying to do and would appreciate any guidance on what the correct approach would be:

## Define the project

```
class Project:
    totalCost=0

    def addDepartment(Dept):
        totalCost+=name.DepartmentCost
        Departments=append(Dept)
```

## Define the department(s)

```
class Department1:
    def __init__(self,Name, NumStaff, AverageStaffSalary)
    Name=None
    NumStaff=None
    AverageStaffSalary=None
    DepartmentCost=AverageStaffSalary*NumStaff
    Department1_SpecificParm=1


class DepartmentN:
    def __init__(self,Name, NumStaff, AverageStaffSalary)
    Name=None
    NumStaff=None
    AverageStaffSalary=None
    DepartmentCost=AverageStaffSalary*NumStaff
    DepartmentN_SpecificParm="A"
```

## Instantiate project and nested departments within it

```
p1=Project("myProject")
p1.addDepartment(Department1(Name="myFirstDepartment", NumStaff=9, AverageStaffSalary=1000))
print p1.myFirstDepartment.DepartmentCost        #Print 9000

p1.addDepartment(DepartmentN(Name="myNthDepartment", NumStaff=2, AverageStaffSalary=6000))
print p1.myNthDepartment.DepartmentCost        #Print 12000
```

## Return total cost across all departments

```
p1.TotalCost          #Print 21000
```

Comment: This smells like homework, is too broad, and your provided code does not make sense and is invalid Python ("as-is"). Focus in some aspect, or improve the structure before asking the question. IMHO

Comment: Unfortunately not homework Markus... Just trying to get a tangible feel for how I need to be building this. I normally use PHP, and as it is such a small task I thought I would try my hand at Python... If anyone can point me in the right direction I promise to come back with non-pseudo code in the future(!)

Comment: Your code doesnt make much sence (even for psudo code) but i think this could be along the lines of what you are looking for. [Repl.it playground](https://repl.it/Hg1D)

Comment: @Olian04 - thank you! :-) Very kind

Comment: @Olian04 in your link - is there a way I can still call elements of individual departments through the project? i.e. `p.deps[2].ppl`

Comment: @Bendy Well yes. The snippet you provided is right, except for the fact that `ppl` never realy is saved in the department instance. However `p.deps[1].cost` would work. _(note: keep in mind that python is 0 indexed, aka accessing the first element in a list = `list[0]`)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posting answer provided in comments)*

Your code doesnt make much sence (even for psudo code) but i think this could be along the lines of what you are looking for. [Repl.it playground](https://repl.it/Hg1D)

```
class Project:
  total = 0
  deps = []

  def addDep(self, dep):
    self.total += dep.cost
    self.deps.append(dep)

class Department:
  def __init__(self, ppl, salary):
    self.cost = ppl * salary

p = Project()
p.addDep(Department(10, 200))
p.addDep(Department(1, 3000))

print(p.total)
```